# Adding Button Control Dynamically and it Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am generating html from a class in Business layer.Here is my Code and its inside a loop.

```
 html = html + "<tr><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["RowNumber"]) + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["ReportName"]) + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["ReportJob"]) + "</td>" +



                    "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["RID"]) + "</td></tr>";  //need to a button or link button to call server side method
```

Is it possible to add buttons and its click event here.

Comment: If you're just generating HTML, then sure.  Just generate the code for a button the same way you generate everything else.  Unless you're referring to something else.

Comment: @AriRoth I have tried like this. Button ButtonChange = new Button();  ButtonChange.Text = "Edit";
                    ButtonChange.ID = "edit_" + Convert.ToString(dr["RID"]);
                    ButtonChange.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(7);
                    ButtonChange.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSubmit_click);   Then RenderControl but its not working . .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your exact need here, but if I understand correctly you are creating a button or a series of buttons in html that need to have an event on the back end to execute code.

What I would do in this case is create a button click even on the back end that checks the text or the name of the calling button and executes the proper code based on your need:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DoSomeCode(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender).Text);
}
```

OR:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Switch(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender).Text)
 {
    Case "Button1":
    //Do something
    Case "Button2":
    //Do something else
    etc....
 }
}
```

When generating the button do something like you need to have a place holder in your html to hold the buttons, then in your code behind you just add them in a loop.:

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Button test = new Button();
        test.Text = i.ToString();
        test.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);

        placeholder.Controls.Add(test);
    }
```

Comment: Concatenating string with asp button? What You have written do you ever tried ?

Comment: Dazzle is correct. I am sorry, I had done this a long time ago, but had not tested when I posted the code. Asp.Net buttons are replaced with html inputs when rendered, so just slapping one into your html won't work. I adjusted my answer to use Asp.net controls dynamically if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

YES YOU can add button dynamically but it should be html button and you must fire the button

by using scripts in your form

in your bussiness layer

```
<td><button onClirntclick='btClick2()'  id=' + Convert.ToString(dr["RID"]' text='submit') +'></button></td></tr>";
```

and in script

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function btClick2()
  {
  return confirm('OnClientClick script: Press OK to continue.');
// do your work
  }
</script>
```

because it will take button as plain text so you must dynamically write the html button

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Of course, browser just takes the code lines and interprets them, so write down your `JavaScript` code that handles your button click, and add it to your `HTML`. Before doing that, I recommend trying it within your browser.